# Setting up angular 2 in visual studio

Tags: angular, visual-studio, angular2-template

I am new to angular 2 , and doing configuration i have done all the requirements but still getting errors .
this is my component

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core"

@Component({

    selector = 'my-app',
    template = `<h1> Hello {{name}} </h1>`
})

 export class AppComponent {

    name: string = "First Project";
}
```

I have installed node.js and quick start files in my root folder already and i already restore packages from packages.json . but i am having this errors when i am building my project

- TS2552 - Can not find name 'selector' Did you mean selection
- TS2304 - Can not find name 'Template

This is my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

this is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": [ "../node_modules/@types" ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

remove '=' and add ':', because it's an object:

```
@Component({

    selector : 'my-app',
    template : `<h1> Hello {{name}} </h1>`
})
```